# How to generate two dependent numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to generate two random numbers
let them x and y,
and i want x to be always greater than y.

how can i do that?

Comment: Define "random" in this case. E.g. what are the min/max? Do you want decimal places? If so, how many? Etc etc

Comment: @Palladium02 or just generate two different numbers and assign the bigger one to `x`

Comment: @VLAZ I agree, except what happens in the rare case where the two numbers are the same? I think you first have to check to see if they are the same and, if so, generate new numbers.

Comment: thats what Math.max and Math.min are for

Comment: Math.random() * (max - min) + min;  See: [MDN Math.random examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#examples)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like that?

```js
// get random number between min and max
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
}

const y = random(0, 10);
const x = random(y + 1, 10);

console.log('x', x);
console.log('y', y);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just generating 2 random values and swapping the values if x is smaller?

```js
let [x,y] = [Math.random(), Math.random()];

console.log(x, y);

if (x < y)
  [x,y] = [y,x];
  
console.log(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/** random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive) */
const random = (min, max) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min;

const generateTwoNumbers = (min, max) => {
  let r1 = random(min, max-1);
  let r2 = random(min, max-1);
  
  if (r2 >= r1)
    r2 += 1;
    
  return [Math.max(r1, r2), Math.min(r1, r2)];
}

const [x, y] = generateTwoNumbers(1, 10);
console.log(`x: ${x} y: ${y}`);
```

First, see [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527803) for how random number generation can be done.

The values `r1` and `r2` are guaranteed to be *different* random numbers in the full range. [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) ensure that the higher of the two is first, the other second.

The function will generate incorrect numbers if the range given is too small, e.g., `generateTwoNumbers(1, 1)` will only produce x = 2 and y = 1. Handling the case of such input is left at the discretion of the reader.

Answer (score 0):

One liner.

```js
// Create a tuple of two random numbers, then sort them.
const randomNumbers = () => [...Array(2)].map(() => Math.random()).sort((a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1));

// test
for (const _ of Array(50).keys()) {
    const [x, y] = randomNumbers();
    console.log(x > y);
}
```